# Loop colouring for bulk data range

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I was trying to fill up the data with background color using the loop. The VBA doesn't show any error for code below, so it seems work. However there is no effect in the sheet.

Could you advise where I have missed something?

My data contain values between row 11 and 14515

I have these data for 31 sections, where every section has 467 rows exactly. I would like to color some of them (every 2), but not all.

```
Sub Background_color2()
    Sheets("14").Activate
    With Range("A479:FI945")
    For n = o To n = 14515 Step 934       '934 rows interval between 2  separate sections
        .Offset(n).Interior.Color = RGB(235, 241, 222)
    Next n
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You seem to have a typo when initializing n in your For loop. And the final value for the offset is probably off. I don't get how you got 14515 from 31x467 (+ 11).

Comment: Roughly should be (468*31)+11, whit gives 14519 rows. I haven't taken into account an empty rows (3 rows between each section). Anyway have you some solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that. Values might need to be adjusted.

```
Sub Background_color2()
    Dim n As Long
    For n = (11 + 468) To (11 + 31 * 468) Step (2 * 468)
        Sheet("14").Cells(n,1).Resize(467, 165).Interior.Color = RGB(235, 241, 222)
    Next n
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Sub Background_color2()

    dim n as long

    With Sheets("14").Range("A479:FI945")
        For n = 0 To 14515 Step 934       '934 rows interval between 2  separate sections
            .Offset(n, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(235, 241, 222)
        Next n
    End With

End Sub
```